# Unknown type name ‘vector’

Tags: templates, vector, include

I have a program written in C++, consisting of 6 classes. Somebody else, who has left, using a version of visual C++, wrote the program. However, the program has no GUIs and is supposed to run in batch mode, generating lots of data (we are talking 100,000+ ASCII files). So, we are thinking that in long term we’ll run it under UNIX.
I have a MacBook air running OS X 10.9.4 and I loaded Xcode 5.1.1

I have quickly examined the 13 files making up the source code and removed various  `#include "StdAfx.h"` statements. Nothing else seems to be non-ANSI compliant. I tried to compile. I get 4 instances of the following error

> Unknown type name ‘vector’

Indeed I have various declarations of the type

```
vector<VariableName*> VariableInstance
```

In my previous experience something like `#include <vector.h>` should work. However, it does not work here.

What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

normally you do

```
#include <vector>
```

then usually you'd do `std::vector<blah>`

however, you can put the following statement before you start using vector, but generally not recommended...

```
using namespace std;
```

and then you can do `vector<blah>`